# Cakephp redirecting a link that has no referer

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.0, before-filter

I've got a submission page that is an ajax popup. If the user isn't logged in, it'll pop up a modal login/signup dialogue for them. Upon logging in, they'll be directed to the main page, since it doesn't remember what the refer was (since all that was triggered as a login page -- not the actual submission page).

I'm thinking of possibly saving that redirect url in a session so when they successfully login, I can redirect them to the appropriate page in my `beforeFilter()` or something...

I was thinking of something like this (pseudo):

```
public function submit() {
    if (!$this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->Session->set('Auth.redirect', '/submit');
    }
}
```

Then in my beforeFilter check to see if that exists when they login, if it does, delete the Session and redirect them to that url?

Is there a better way to handle this or is mine legit?

My beforeFilter:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => '', 'action' => 'login');

    $this->Auth->allow(
            'Search',
            'loginSignUpPrompt'
            );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the Auth Component already has this functionality built in.

```
public function login() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
      return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
    }
  }
}
```

The default for this method is the page where the user came from. But that can be overridden in the Auth settings if you wanted it to.

Refer to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html the section about "Identifying users and logging them in"

Comment: Ah, I was using `$this->redirect($this->referer())` but now if I use the built-in method, if I go to say `/submit` it'll prompt me to login  with a login form, but once I do login, it'll take me back to the `/login` page. Any idea why?

Comment: Updated and added it to original post.

Comment: Yeah, you need to remove the line, `$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => '', 'action' => 'login');` That is sending it back to the login page instead of the default, sending it to the referer.

Comment: If I get rid of that and go to say `/submit` it'll show my session flash for not being logged in, but won't redirect to the actual login page which is what I need... Any idea?

Comment: Check out the section labeled Authentication (login and logout). http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html. It shows the loginRedirect is to redirect after the login to somewhere specific. Otherwise the default is the referer. I am not sure why you are getting the result you have but look over this documentation and see if you missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this->redirect($this->referer());` unless the user has to enter some kind of form data (like in your login example).  When I run into instances like that I pretty much do what you are doing and store the previous URL in a session variable then destroy that variable when I redirect them back to the original URL.  There is a beforeRedirect() callback component you may be interested in using [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html).